# Farelogix Trace Tool Configuration for Production

Tags: configuration

I am looking for the configuration of Farelogix Trace Tool for Production Environment. I need to know the host and the port for Production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They dont have tracing enabled for production. It adds a lot of overhead to trace and impacts performance.